# Establish ethernet connection in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, connection, lan, ethernet

Can you tell me please how can I establish/tear down an existing ethernet (LAN) connection using C#?

In Windows UI it's quite simple, you're clicking right mouse button on the connection and choosing "Connect"/"Disconnect" command from the context menu. Is there any programmatic analogue of that action? It seemed rather simple to me but eventually I've found nothing on this matter. I found how to check a connection status, how to enumerate all the network interfaces, how to dial a 3G modem connection, how to enable/disable a network card, how to monitor availability of the net, etc, anything but this! Generally I need a software switcher that will be able to turn on and off an ethernet connection (not a network card!).

Isn't there a simple method something like `GetConnection(connectionName).Connect()`?

Comment: Isn't enable/disable what you're looking for? Or what operation exactly do you want to perform? You can't connect/disconnect a LAN interface in software, that is done by plugging it in physically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately enabling/disabling of a network card isn't what I'm looking for. Network card may be physically plugged in and enabled as well but a connection may be still not established (for example, for the virtual network card - one of my cases which I want to resolve).

Answer (score 0):

Make some searches on TCP/IP Client/Server modeling in c#, you actually can start by some already existing sample codes like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5733/A-TCP-IP-Server-written-in-C)

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at it, but it seems like a far too complicated solution for my simple task. It's rather strange that I have to create TCP sockets, client, server and so on just to use an already existing Ethernet connection...

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet doesn't have a concept of "connected" or "disconnected".  It is really a multiple random access medium.  Also, I'm not sure what UI element you are talking about.  On my machine, I can "connect/disconnect" wireless adapters, but not Ethernet adapters.  This is because most wireless protocols have an actual concept of being "connected" to some access point.  If you are really talking about a wireless adapter, I'm sure there are windows API's that can control them, but I don't know off hand where to point you.  Otherwise, I think you might need to take a step back and explain the larger context of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I have a virtual network card created by a 3G modem, it is connecting to the Internet using not a RAS connection, but NDIS protocol. "Virtual" network card is present in the list of the network adapters, and I can click "Connect" on it and it asks me for login/pwd/etc. I hope this clear a bit my situation...

Comment: Ah yes, 3G (i.e., either 1xRTT, 1xEVDO, WCDMA) all have concepts of being "connected" or "disconnected".  Although the device drivers for these devices (except for some, starting with Windows 7) provide an ethernet interface to the upper layers (TCP/IP driver), they aren't actually ethernet devices themselves.  I'm not sure off hand what mechanism is used to tell the driver to connect/disconnect, but I think it will be specific to this type of adapter, not a general property of all ethernet adapters.